# How to use custom material icons in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to use custom SVG icons following the material.angular.io example. I am using a service that contains the `initCustomIcons` function. The log shows that the function runs properly when called.

.TS:

```ts
constructor(
        private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
        private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer
    ) { }

public initCustomIcons() {
        console.log('registered.');
        this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
            'file-pdf',
            this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('assets/icons/file-pdf.svg')
        );
        this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
            'file-excel',
            this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('assets/icons/file-excel.svg')
        );
        this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
            'file-delimited',
            this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('assets/icons/file-delimited.svg')
        );
    }
```

HTML:

```html
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="exportToPDF($event)" [disabled]="disabledBtn"> Export <mat-icon svgIcon="file-pdf"></mat-icon> </button>
```

I get the error shown below. I have tried different ways to fix it but I cannot find anything that works. Any help would be appreciated.

ERROR:

```
Error retrieving icon: Unable to find icon with the name ":file-pdf"
```

Comment: Where did you call `initCustomIcons` in? I believe that the initialisation of icons can be done when a component is initially created (i.e. in the `constructor` field).

Comment: I get this error when unit testing. I've been at it for a few hours and I suppose I don't understand this enough to figure out why I'm getting this error.